# Unable to fetach all data in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following controller where I get the records based on user login. its work successfully but I want to make an admin who fetch all the user data. my mind is not getting any idea how to do that. pls, help me. my method for fetch user data is following.

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['user_id'];
    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('posts');

        $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id= posts.user_id');
        $this->db->where('users.id',$user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: So you want admin users to see all posts from all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes: (Read the comments carefully.)

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['user_id'];
    $user_type = $this->session->userdata['userType'];  // Assuming that you would be storing user role in session with 'userType' key
    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('posts');

        $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id= posts.user_id');
        if($user_type != 'admin'){  // Then fetch all post of logged in user. Otherwise all post of all the users will be fetched.
            $this->db->where('users.id',$user_id);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: Great.. its work but i am facing a problem if any user knows url then he can logged in and direct type another person product url and it'll display. that should not be every user can view own page nothing else except admin

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the user role stored in the session you should fetch the current user data again:

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }

    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['user_id'];

    // Fetch current user from db
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('users.id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $user = $query->row_array();

    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('posts');

        $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id');

        if(!$user['is_admin']){  // Assuming that you would be storing if user is admin in database in a 'is_admin' field
            $this->db->where('users.id',$user_id);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE, $is_admin = FALSE){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');        
    if(!$is_admin){
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id');
        $this->db->where('users.id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    }
    if($slug){ $this->db->where('posts.slug', $slug); }        
    if($limit){ $this->db->limit($limit, $offset); }
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();        
    return ($query->num_rows() > 1) ? $query->result_array() : $query->row_array();
}
```

**USAGE**

```
// In USER (same like you are calling now)
$posts = get_posts();

// In ADMIN
$posts = get_posts(false, false, false, true);
```